# Listen to file dropped in openlayers 3 Drag and Drop interaction

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to display an `SHP file` into `openlayers 3 map`. I found a library to read both .shp and .dbf files, so I can read features and attributes from the files. Now I want the client to drop those files to the map using `DragAndDrop` interaction.

Is possible to do this?

Is there an event similar to bellow example?

```
dragAndDrop.on('file-drop', function(event){
  // Do something with event.file or event.someKey
});
```

In this event (if exist) should I parse the files, get features and add to map manually?

Also if this kind of event exist what would happen with addfeatures event.

Will be triggered??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use ondrop event of HTML,
then get Geojson data from that library you found, and then create a vector layer

Comment: It's a good solution. I'll try it. Thanks for the response! =)